How to maintain the continuity in connecter lines for zero values in a Plotly.js Waterfall Chart?
I'm working with a Waterfall chart in Plotly.js and facing an issue where the connecting lines between bars break when any of the values are zero. I want to maintain the continuity of the connecting lines even if there are zero values in the dataset.
Here’s a simplified version of my code:
const capex = this.data["CapEx ($/Kg)"] || 0;
const stackReplacements = this.data["Stack Replacements ($/Kg)"] || 0;
const electricityCost = this.data["Electricity Cost ($/Kg)"] || 0;
const fixedOpex = this.data["Fixed Opex ($/Kg)"] || 0;
const ptc = this.data["Production Tax Credit ($/Kg)"] || 0;
const lcoh = capex + stackReplacements + electricityCost + fixedOpex;
const post45VLCOH = lcoh + ptc;    
const yValues = [capex, stackReplacements, electricityCost, fixedOpex, lcoh, ptc, post45VLCOH];
const smallValue = 0.001; // Small value to replace zero
const adjustedYValues = yValues.map(value => value === 0 ? smallValue : value);
const textValues = yValues.map(value => value.toFixed(2));

const trace = {
  type: 'waterfall',
  name: 'Waterfall Chart',
  orientation: 'v',
  measure: ['relative', 'relative', 'relative', 'relative', 'total', 'relative', 'total'],
  x: ['Capex', 'Cell service', 'Electricity', 'Fixed Opex', 'LCOH', 'PTC', 'Post-45V LCOH'],
  y: adjustedYValues,
  connector: { 
    line: { 
      color: 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5)',
      width: 1,
      dash: 'solid' // Set the line style
    }
  },
  decreasing: { marker: { color: '#F066AC' } },
  increasing: { marker: { color: '#046CC4' } },
  totals: { marker: { color: '#3C8454' } },
  text: textValues,
  textposition: 'outside',
};

const layout = {
  xaxis: {
    fixedrange: true,
  },
  yaxis: {
    title: 'Contributions to LCOH ($/Kg)',
    fixedrange: true,
  },
  showlegend: false,
  dragmode: false,
  bargap: 0.3,
  margin: { t: 50, b: 50, r: 50, l: 50 },
};

const options = {
  responsive: true,
  displayModeBar: true,
  modeBarButtonsToRemove: ['select2d', 'lasso2d'],
  toImageButtonOptions: {
    format: 'png',
    filename: 'LCOH Breakdown',
    height: 500,
    width: 700,
    scale: 1,
  },
  displaylogo: false,
};

Plotly.newPlot(this.elementRef.nativeElement, [trace], layout, options);

When I run this code, the connecting lines break at the "Zero" value. Is there a way to modify the chart or the data so that the lines remain continuous throughout the chart, regardless of zero values? Any suggestions or workarounds would be greatly appreciated!
